# Como obtener numero de filas y columnas de una matriz declarada con punteros

Tags: c++, array, funciones, punteros

Código:

```cpp
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>
    using namespace std;

    int **mbd(int f, int c){
        int **m = new int *[f];
        for (int i=0;i<f;i++){ *(m+i)= new int [c]; }
        return m;
        }

    int nfilas(int **m){ return sizeof(m)/sizeof(*m); }

    int main(){ 
        int **matrix=mbd(3,5);
        cout<<nfilas(matrix); // salida: 1 , esperado: 3
        return 0;
    }
```

Por lo que he estado viendo el error creo está en que la función mbd retorna un puntero y no toda la matriz. Estuve probando con las siguientes instrucciones dentro de la funcion mdb:

```
cout<<sizeof(m)   // salida: 8 que es (1*2*sizeof(int)) , esperado: 60 que es (3*5*sizeof(int))
cout<<sizeof(*m)  // salida: 8 que es (2*sizeof(int)) , esperado:  20 que es (5*sizeof(int))
```

Sé que una solución podría ser declarar todo dentro de main() en lugar de usar funciones, y declarar la matriz de esta manera: int m[3][5] (en lugar de hacerlo como se hizo en la funcion mbd() ).
¿Hay alguna otra solución donde pueda seguir utilizando las funciones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No se puede conseguir el tamaño de un array declarado con punteros. Si necesitas el tamaño, tienes que guardarlo y pasarlo a cualquiera que lo necesite.

Hay muchas soluciones que te permiten utilizar las funciones.

- usar int m[3][5] como has comentado
- usar std::vector (usa la memoria heap como tu implementación)
- usar std::array (si quieres una matriz en la pila)
- implementar tu propia matriz, por ejemplo:

  template 
  struct Matrix
  {
      int _matrix[F][C];
  };